# My ntfs partition has no files in it but it shows half full when checked in properties & GParted

Tags: ntfs, partitioning, file-properties

The partition name is "New Volume" and its size is 68gb(when viewed in Gparted). it contains no files. but still its properties show that it has 41.3gb used and 32.1gb free.

> Here are the images.
>
> Its properties: see contents section
>   [image: Its properties: see contents section]
>
> GParted image Its the dev/sda6 partition. 
>   [image: GParted image. dev/sda6]
>
> Please Help!!

Comment: The most probable reason is that files where trashed from the partition, but not deleted. The files are (probably) in the trash

Comment: yes! just emptied the trash and the drive showed empty in properties. can't believe how i missed it!!. thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the partition appears to have no files, but still seems occupied for a large amount of space, the most probable reason is that a number of files on the partition was moved to trash, but the trash was not emptied. (for a while, looking at the amount of space :) )

Just empty the trash and I expect you can use the full partition again.